# Como contar quantas vezes um valor aparece em tabela

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como contar quantas vezes um valor aparece em uma tabela ?

Exemplo:

```
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td> 2 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 6 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 2 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 1 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

O 2 aparece duas vezes, o 6 uma vez e o 1 uma vez...

**OBS: lembrando que os numeros mudam e são aleatorios...**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode criar elementos HTML para ir guardando/exibindo a contagem:

```
$('#table td').each(function (i, e) {
    if ($('[data-numero=' + $(this).text() + ']').length) {
        var numero = $('[data-numero=' + $(this).text() + ']').children('span');
        numero.text( parseInt(numero.text()) + 1 );
    } else {
        $('body').append('<div data-numero="' + $(this).text() + '">Número ' + $(this).text() + ': <span>1</span></div>');
    }
});
```

veja funcionando no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/jz6Lewny)

Answer (score 13):

Basta usar um [dicionário](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/magazine/cc163419.aspx#S1) que tenha por chaves os valores nas células ;)

Tipo assim:

```
var dicionarioDeValores = {};

$("#table")
        .find("td")
        .each(function (index, elem) {
    var valor = $(elem).text();
    if (!dicionarioDeValores[valor]) {
        dicionarioDeValores[valor] = 1;
    } else {
        dicionarioDeValores[valor]++;
    }
});
```

Você vai percorrer todas as células. Cada vez que entrar em uma célula, se o valor dela já for chave do dicionário, você incrementa. Caso contrário, você inicializa com 1. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: No jQuery o primeiro argumento do `each()` é o index, não o elemento. Deve usar o `this` ou `function (i, elem)`. O MooTools é que tem o elemento como primeiro parametro.

Comment: Valeu pelo toque, ajeitei :)

Comment: @Renan E como ficaria a resposta nessa formatação "2 = 2, 6 = 1, 1 = 1" ??

Comment: 1 ocorrência de cada. Se você quiser contar os números individuais, precisa refinar a lógica mais ainda.

Comment: @Renan, pode me dar um exemplo de como fazer ?

Comment: @AlanPS no seu comentário, você quer contar uma ocorrência de `2 = 2`, ou duas ocorrências de `2`? Com mais detalhes podemos lhe ajudar melhor ;)

Comment: @Renan, já consegui resolver o problema, usei o seu exemplo ai de cima mesmo e coloquei o resultado em um array usando um FOR!!! Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Eu resolvi fazer em Javascript puro, só para ter mais uma opção de pesquisa:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Tabela</title>
<script type="text/javascript">                
        Calcular = function(id){
            var table = document.getElementById(id);
            var td    = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
            var dados = {};
            for(i = 0; i < td.length; i++)
            {
                dados[td[i].innerHTML] = (dados[td[i].innerHTML] === undefined)? 1: (dados[td[i].innerHTML] + 1);                
            }
            console.log(dados);
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="table">
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="button" onclick="Calcular('table')">Calcular</button>
</body>
</html>
```

***Exemplo Online:*** [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ezd74p0g/1/)

*Obs: no meu exemplo existe mais td e por isso muda a numeração.*

Answer (score 1):

Este é um caso onde você pode se beneficiar de [arrays associativos](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/1441-javascript-data-structures-the-associative-array.html).

```
//Array associativo
var histograma = {};

// A função abaixo é chamada para cada célula:
$('table#table tr td').each(function() {
    var chave = $(this).text();       // A chave do histograma
    var val = histograma[chave] || 0; //Caso o valor não exista, assuma zero
    histograma[chave] = val + 1;      //Contagem de ocorrências
});

// Listando o resultado do método acima:
for (var chave in histograma) {
    $('#res').append(chave + ':' + histograma[chave] + '<br/>'); 
}
```

O resultado desse snippet é o seguinte:

```
Tabela:
2
6
2
1
Ocorrências:
2 :2
6 :1
1 :1
```

[Aqui vai o JSFiddle de exemplo.](http://jsfiddle.net/dkcuLsmg/)

<sub>(Edit - após ler as outras respostas, esta é basicamente uma versão um pouco mais enxuta da resposta de [Renan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/1658/renan).)</sub>